# Android Styles.xml can't find @drawable selector for TextView textColor

Tags: android, textview, xamarin, android-drawable, android-styles

I have a TextView. I have a selector to change the text colour on press.
If I reference the selector inline (like below), it works.

```
<TextView style="@style/DefaultLinkText" android:textColor="@drawable/tmp_hyperlink_textColor"/>
```

If I move the inline reference into a style in the Styles.xml, it can't find it.

```
<style name="DefaultLinkText">
 <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/tmp_hyperlink_textColor</item>
 <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas why it can't find my drawable selector? I reference other drawables within my styles, but they are for background not textColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searching... I found that I was referencing it correctly, but it didn't like the file name!
So I changed my file name from:
tmp_hyperlink_textColor to:
tmp_hyperlink_text_color

It didn't like the textColor name in the file name! So I must remember to name all xml files with lower case underscores.